# EXC_BAD_ACCESS iOS error

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I know, I know. I've Google and searched here but can't figure out what's going on.

Anyway, i'm getting this error when using the following code, i'm sure it's something small. I know it's to do with memory management and down to how i'm handling my object in the main method.

Here's my main code:

```
Person *p1 = [[Person alloc] init];
[p1 initWithFirstname:@"John" lastname:@"Doe" andAge:23];

outputText.text = [p1 getDetails]; // App crashes inside getDetails
```

Then in the person class here's the two relevant methods:

```
-(Person *)initWithFirstname:(NSString *)_firstname lastname:(NSString *)_lastname andAge:
(int)_age {
self = [super init];

if(self) {
self.firstname = _firstname;
self.lastname = _lastname;
self.age = _age;

}
return self;
}


-(NSString *)getDetails {
 return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@, %@", firstname, lastname, age];
}
```

Comment: it can be autorelease issue . just try -(NSString *)getDetails {
 return [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@, %@", firstname, lastname, age]retain];
} please provide more detail about the crash

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Judging by your `init` method, `age` is an `int` which means the format specifier is wrong.  Try this:

```
-(NSString *)getDetails 
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@, %d", firstname, lastname, age];
    //                                         ^^ format specifier for an int
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jeremy, that was the problem.

Now, I must say that the error wasn't very helpful. I thought it was a memory management error. I wonder why NSString couldn't throw an exception and give a more meaningful error.

Thanks again.

Comment: @Conor H: The error in question is an underlying operating system error.  In OS X, the operating system protects the first page (4096 bytes) of memory so that programs can't read or write it.  This is to trap dereferences of null pointers.  NSString couldn't throw an exception because it never got a chance - the OS terminated the process.

Answer (score 5):

You've written an initialization method, then called `init` twice. Just try:

```
Person *p1 = [[Person alloc] initWithFirstname:@"John" lastname:@"Doe" andAge:23];

outputText.text = [p1 getDetails];
```

Answer (score 2):

You're first calling the default `init` of your newly allocated object. That `init` returns a pointer to your object which you store in `p1`. Then you call `initWithFirstname:lastname:andAge:` on `p1`, which is wrong as you've already called another initializer first. You're only supposed to run one initializer.

You need to do:

```
Person *p1 = [[Person alloc] initWithFirstname:@"John" lastname:@"Doe" andAge:23];
```

But your **crash** stems from the fact that you pass the number `23` to the format specifier `%@`. You need to use `%d` for the age instead. Also, you should retain the first and last name (and release them in your `dealloc`) to avoid any crashes later on when using non-const strings.

What happens is that because of `%@`, the NSLog tries to treat the 23 as a pointer to an object and wants to call the `description` method of the supposed object. But 23 is an invalid/unused address, and trying to access the memory at that "address" is what makes your app crash.